# Hyperlinking value in JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs, translation

I have translation json file that would contain appropriate text. I would like to hyper link a single word from my sentence

json file where all values stored

```
  "noDocuments": "No documents found, please contact HR Here"
```

This is how i refer to my json file in a one of the components

```
return <Translation>
        {(t) => {
            if (this.state.loading) {
                return (
                    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <Spin/>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            if (this.state.metaInfoDocs.length === 0) {
                return (
                    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <NoDocumentsAlert>{t('noDocuments')}</NoDocumentsAlert>
                    </div>
                )
            }
```

I just want to know if it's possible to some how write htmt in my json file so I could hyper link a single word, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: jsonFile.noDocuments }}></div>
```

This is similar to the innerHTML in JS. See [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I take an assumption here form the `{t()}` syntax that you are using [react i18next](https://react.i18next.com/)

The package has a `Trans` component that allows you to have something like this:

```
<Trans i18nKey="noDocuments">No documents found, please contact HR Here: <a href="">Link</a></Trans>
```

This will come up like this in your JSON:

```
"noDocuments": "No documents found, please contact HR Here: <1>Link</1>"
```

Comment: Your answer is clear and super helpful but i actually needed to refer to json file that contain string  and  somehow i needed to insert a link in the middle of my string  so  i had to the following <NoDocumentsAlert><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: t('noDocuments')}}/></NoDocumentsAlert>

Comment: Be careful with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` it can lead to XSS if the data is coming from a compromised source.